# :video_player_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac (video player android package)

Tags: android, flutter, compiler-errors, build.gradle

I have problem with this package when add it to my flutter project

it is called video player package

it is fine when run app on ios but when try to run it on android emulator it gives me this error

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':video_player_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

and if i remove this package from my project it is worked with me without any problem

How can i use this package without any problem and work correctly on android emulator?

Answer (score 1):

Try to run this :
./gradlew compileDebugJavaWithJavac